# Why does this happen in my template for Django?

Tags: python, django

simple%20minds is displayed when do this:

{{ rec.artist_name }}

How do I remove the %20...and make it spaces?

When I put | safe as a fitler, the error is:

Could not parse the remainder: ' | safe' from 'active.artist_name | safe'

Thanks.

Comment: What is rec? How are you passing it in? I presume that you're taking it from a GET variable and passing it into the view as a context variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're being hit by Django's relatively-new autoescaping.  What happens if you do

```
{{ rec.artist_name | safe }}
```

to avid the value being autoescaped?

Comment: Hi Alexa, I've tried that, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Could not parse the remainder:

Comment: is the %20 also stored in db?

Comment: Actually, this is applied to it before I shoot it to the template.

urllib.quote(q.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: Then that is the expected output - urllib.quote will replace spaces with %20. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the space between the rec.artist_name and the |. So you should have this:

`{{ rec.artist_name|safe }}`

That'll fix the autoescaping, but I think the other commentors are correct in saying that you're storing the %20 into the db. So you'll probably have to fix it on that end of things.